# How do I run our qunit tests from rake?

Tags: rake, qunit

I would like to be able to issue the command `rake test:qunit` and to have our qunit tests run.  Is this possible?  Can it be done without opening a browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could integrate PhantomJS into rake. PhantomJS can run QUnit tests and provides useful results, as its using an actual browser engine (WebKit). [PhantomJS has an example on integrating QUnit.](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/ServiceIntegration)

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: https://github.com/jodosha/hanoi